# Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(App) /> outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to rimplement server-side rendering in my React App. In the server.js I'm just listening for any route (`/*`) and generate a string with the react server and send it back.

But the "withRouter" is complaining because it thinks it is not inside a router. But it clearly is. This is very strange.

**client/src/App.js**

```js
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<div>Hello</div>)
    }
}
export default withRouter(App)
```

**server/index.js**

```js
const content = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter location={location} context={context}>
            <App/>
        </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
);
```

```
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(App) /> outside a <Router>
    at invariant (webpack-internal:///./client/node_modules/tiny-invariant/dist/tiny-invariant.esm.js:11:11)
    at Object.eval [as children] (webpack-internal:///./client/node_modules/react-router/esm/react-router.js:729:88)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3635:55)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3373:29)
    at Object.renderToString (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:3988:27)
    at _callee2$ (webpack-internal:///./server/index.js:137:38)
    at tryCatch (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:274:22)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (webpack-internal:///./server/index.js:7:103)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the reference to the `StaticRouter` must be EXACTLY the same.

So the solution was to use the SAME `StaticRouter` export for both (client and server). Essentially, doing in the server code:

```
const { StaticRouter } = require('../client/node_modules/react-router-dom');
```

Hope this helps someone.